# Distinguish document title versus section title

Tags: python, docutils

In the [Docutils document tree](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/doctree.html), a `title` node may occur inside a section, or inside the document itself.

For a particular Docutils `NodeVisitor` I am creating, I need to be able to distinguish whether the current `title` node is the document's title, or is instead within one of several sections in the document: if it's actually the title of the overall document, I just want to skip this title and move on.

I would have expected to be able to do this within `Visitor.visit_title`:

```python
class DocumentTitleSkippingVisitor:

    # …

    def visit_title(self, node):
        document_node = section_node.parent
        if section_node is document_node:
            # This title is actually the document's top level title.
            raise self._docutils.nodes.SkipNode
```

That doesn't work, though: the visitor encounters the document's top level title inside another `section` node. Because of this, the above check (correctly) says the parent of the `title` is *not* the `document` node.

How can I tell, within the `NodeVisitor`, that the `title` is actually the special document title? Alternatively, how can I hook into Docutils such that the `title` is actually at the document level, to more easily distinguish it from a `section` title?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `visit_section` and `depart_section`:

```
class DocumentTitleSkippingVisitor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.in_section = False
    def visit_section(self, node):
        self.in_section = True
    def depart_section(self,node):
        self.in_section = False
    def visit_title(self, node):
        if self.in_section:
            pass # do something
```

For reStructuredText there is no way to specify a document title and subtitle explicitly. In this case:

- You can first apply [DocTitle](https://sourceforge.net/p/docutils/code/HEAD/tree/tags/docutils-0.10/docutils/transforms/frontmatter.py#122)
- You should follow the algorithm used by [DocTitle](https://sourceforge.net/p/docutils/code/HEAD/tree/tags/docutils-0.10/docutils/transforms/frontmatter.py#122) to find it.

Comment: Have you confirmed this would work? My experience suggests it would fail in the same way: the visitor encounters the document-level title inside a `section`.

Answer (score 0):

The `docutils.writers._html_base` writer uses:

```
def visit_title(self, node):
    [...]
        elif isinstance(node.parent, nodes.document):
            self.body.append(self.starttag(node, 'h1', '', CLASS='title'))
    [...]
```

to detect and style the document title.

Mind, that this requires running `docutils.transforms.frontmatter.DocTitle` first.
This is the default behaviour with Docutils unless the [doctitle-xform](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/config.html#doctitle-xform) setting is False (or the `--no-section-subtitles` command line option given to the front-end tool).